# Density estimation for points regularly spaced on a grid? Infer spacing between pdf peaks?

Tags: variance, nonparametric, density-function, inference, density-estimation

Due to a fundamental characteristic of the data, points are clustered together on a 1-D grid-like structure with equal spacing.

Plotting these points in a histogram shows a pdf with several individual peaks.

What clustering techniques could I use to infer the variance (the width) of each of these peaks, as well as the number of peaks?

Is this done with density estimation? Maybe Dirichlet processes?

Comment: Maybe Gaussian Mixture Models?

Comment: @AlexR. Can you explain how you would do this?